# Ionic context.getProjectMetadata is not a function [Live Reload only]

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm facing an issue with ionic live reload failing to build due to the error "context.getProjectMetaData is not a function"
I am just encountering this issue after installing the Firebase cloud messaging cordova plugin and npm package (for push notifications). Im unsure if this would the issue as the app build and launches without live reload. (and fcm works properly)

This is the error log im getting, anyone experienced this before?

```
[error] TypeError: context.getProjectMetadata is not a function
    at Object.configureI18nBuild (..\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\i18n-options.js:99:36)
    at Object.generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (..\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:85:57)
    at Object.buildBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (..\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:67:41)
    at setup ..\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:103:63)
```

Comment: Have you set the angular version to version 9 ? It can be due to this :
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/164#issuecomment-588366462

Comment: @Noelmout that doesn't seem to be an issue as all of the angular packages are on the same version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started having this problem after I ran `npm audit fix` because I wanted to have a project that's clean of vulnerabilities.

It seems, `npm audit fix` command is rather greedy. It silently upgraded my `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.25"` to version 0.9, thus breaking my Angular 8 app with the same `context.getProjectMetadata is not a function` error.

Morale of the story - be very careful with `npm audit fix` and inspect what it does to your `package.json`.

Comment: So how do you fix this issue after getting this error?

Comment: Reverted the changes done by `npm audit fix`:  Deleted `package-lock.json` file. Then manually fixed `package.json` file to have the right library versions (Angular 8, not 9) and run `npm install` again to refetch correct versions and generate a new `package-lock.json` file.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this same issue when updating from angular 8 to 9, what fixed it for me was:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/architect@latest
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
```

Found original solution at
https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/215#issuecomment-612616498

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that these two packages have the same version and that the version compatible with your angular version.

```
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1001.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.4",
```